# Gmail API / Google Auth - How to get verified?

Tags: gmail-api, google-authentication

[image: Google Error]

I have created an app with Gmail API / Google Auth in Vue.js and Laravel that can read and send emails on a user's behalf.   My code works fine, however I see this error screen before a user can authorize the access to their inbox.  Apparently there is some verification process that Google has not documented anywhere.  I even opened a ticket with Google but no answer.  I was wondering if anyone here knows how to get it verified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OAuth Client Verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)

> Starting July 18, 2017, Google OAuth clients that request certain sensitive OAuth scopes will be subject to review by Google.

OAuth Client Verification
Starting July 18, 2017, Google OAuth clients that request certain sensitive OAuth scopes will be subject to review by Google.

Review is not required for Apps Script projects whose owner and users belong to the same G Suite domain or customer.
Users from outside the developer’s domain accessing the OAuth prompt for a client that has not been reviewed and verified will see a new unverified app screen, and the number of such users will be capped. An unverified authorization flow allows users to authorize unverified apps, but only after confirming they understand the risks. You can read more about this change in this [help center article](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865).

This change applies to Google OAuth web clients, including those used by all Apps Script projects. [By verifying your app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#requesting_verification) with Google, you can remove the unverified app screen from your authorization flow and give your users confidence that your app is non-malicious.

Once you have applied for verification it takes around a week and it should start working.